# Реализации плавной анимации в Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, css3, vue.js

Как задать для анимации чтобы она плавно появлялась - как сейчас у меня реализовано. Так и плавно изчезала, а не резко, как
сдалано на `keyframes`:

```
export const fadeleft = keyframes`
from {
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   opacity: 0;
}
to {
   transform: translateX(0);
   opacity: 1;
}
`;
```

В стилях обьекта:

```
animation: ${fadeleft} .4s ease ;
```

Comment: Ну сделайте на JS это. GSAP подключите какой-нибудь и сделайте, там совсем все легко.

Comment: какой gsap?! я описал проблему

Comment: Загуглите что такое gsap, это не сложно. Разберитесь, получите отличную, плавную, красивую анимацию на JS. Со реактивными фреймворками типа vue работать с этой библиотекой одно удовольствие.

Comment: gsap мне не нужен. Спасибо, но не катит.

Answer (score 1):

На `Vue.js` анимацию правильно реализовать нужно через встроенный компонент `transition`, на который нам нужно добавить атрибут с именем анимируемого блока, на который `Vue` добавляет классы для анимации.

Нам же остаётся написать правильно разметку и завязаться на классы с переходами:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#test',
    data: {
        show: false
    }
})
```

```css
.fade-enter-active, .fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .25s;
}

.fade-enter, .fade-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="test">
    <button v-on:click="show = !show">
        <span v-if="!show">
            Открыть анимацию
        </span>
        <span v-else>
            Закрыть анимацию
        </span>
    </button>

    <transition name="fade">
        <p v-if="show">
            Я анимируюсь!
        </p>
    </transition>
</div>
```

Comment: всё очень круто, но я не могу использовать классы)

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom почему?)

Comment: У меня styled-components на Vue) Сам бы юзал класссы - но нет))

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom так добавьте стили не в компонент, а в отдельный СSS-файл. СSS же у вас есть?)

Comment: неа) всё чисто на компонентах ) типа css in JS

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom напридумывают модной херни)

Comment: @svitalik1999gmailcom тогда в вашей анимации добавьте промежуточные состояния, типа:

keyframes squash {
        20% {
            transform: scaleY(0.9);
        }
        40% {
            transform: scaleY(1.1);
        }
        60% {
            transform: scaleY(0.9);
        }
    }

Comment: Ну хорошо а как тогда отследить когда элемент станет в false, мне кажется так это не заработает

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам надо, чтобы элемент один раз плавно появился и плавно исчез, то измените анимацию и добавьте в стили `forwards` - это позволит сохранить состояние после завершения:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: fade 1s ease forwards;
}
@keyframes fade {
  0% {
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
     transform: translateX(0);
     opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

А можете добавить в стили `infinite alternate` и таким образом зациклить Вашу анимацию :)

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: fadeleft .4s ease infinite alternate;
}
@keyframes fadeleft {
  from {
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
     transform: translateX(0);
     opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: мне нужно чтобы он плавно изчезал тогда - когда он станет в false

Comment: Хотел поставить watch - но так не срабол потому что по умолчанию у меня элемент уже в false. Дальше он становится в True (конечно с анимацией). Дальше мы можем его закрыть - чтобы он тоже плавно инимировался в false. Извеняюсь